# Attempting to retrieve specific column from first row

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to retrieve the data from the first row in column `MainPage`.
Here's the code I used:

```
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","---","---","---");
// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
  {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
  }


$result = mysql_query($con,"SELECT concat (MainPage) from content");
$row = mysql_fetch_row($result);
echo $row[0]; 

mysqli_close($con);
```

Here's the error I received:

> Warning: mysql_query(): supplied argument is not a valid MySQL-Link
>   resource in ... on line 17

Any idea why?
Thanks!

Comment: concat (MainPage) will never work what you are conceiting MainPage with ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you mixed between mysql and mysqli.
try this

```
 $result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT concat(MainPage) as mainp from content");
 $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
 echo $row['mainp'];
```

Answer (score 1):

```
resource mysql_query ( string $query [, resource $link_identifier = NULL ] )
```

`$con` is the second parameter

You are also using `mysqli_connect`, but `mysql_query`. You should use `mysqli_query`

Answer (score 0):

You could ORDER BY:

> $result = mysql_query($con,"SELECT concat (MainPage) from content
>   `order by MainPage limit 1`");

If it's a large dataset, you may want to consider adding an index upon MainPage.